# Cuando se termine de ejecutar una función, se ejecute otra

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

Estoy cargando múltiples ventanas modal con diferente información de acuerdo al usuario.

Lo que hice fue colocar el modal en otro archivo, y al momento hacer `click` en el botón del usuario cargar el modal dependiendo de la información que el usuario tenga.

Mi problema es que al hacer`click` en el botón, el modal carga, pero existen errores por lo que la pantalla se cuelga o el modal carga y luego desaparece.

Lo que intento hacer es que al darle `click` en el botón cargue mis ventanas modales y luego se ejecute el código del modal, pero no funciona correctamente.

¿Existe una manera de cargar primero los elementos modales y luego cargar la función de muestra de modal?

Dejo el pequeño código que estoy implementando.

```js
function modalCall(id,modal,callback) {
        $('#modales_transferencia').load('../tools/modales_transferencia.php?id='+id);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#'+modal).modal();
        }, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Si especificaras que tipo de errores te muestra, podria ayudarte.

Comment: No me muestra errores, el código funciona. El problema es que a veces el modal no carga o bien carga y desaparece. Esto quizás sucede porque no hace la carga de elementos y la muestra del modal en orden secuencial. Por tal motivo quisiera ejecutar una función tras otra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL tiempo que demora la carga puede variar (resultado *asincrono*), y tomar mas del tiempo que dejas de timeout (200 ms). Debes incluir dicho codigo en la funcion callback que se ejecutara luego de cargar el contenido con `$.load(url, callback)`

```
function modalCall(id,modal,callback) {
        $('#modales_transferencia').load('../tools/modales_transferencia.php?id='+id, function (){
            $('#'+modal).modal();
        });
        
    }
```

https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba.